# Why is this function periodic for only certain values of k.

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, periodic-functions

Lets start by defining the function in question;

$y(t)= \frac{\pi{sin(kt)}-ksin{(\pi{t}})}{\pi^{2}k-k^{3}}$

Now the question.

So from what i gather the function is periodic when $k=n\pi\;$ ,   $\;\forall n \in \mathbb{R}$, except when $n=1$ which causes resonance.

Why is this the case? For example why is it not periodic when $k=1$?

Comment: There seems to be some confusion here.  You have $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $n=\pi.$  Also $k=n\pi$ and $k=1$.

Comment: Sorry about that, I've edited it, it should have been the real numbers.

Comment: But then shouldn't the last phrase be "when $k=\pi?$"

Comment: No, it's the rational numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $y(t)$ is periodic with period $T$, that means

$$ \pi \sin(k(t+T)) - k \sin(\pi (t+T)) = \pi \sin(kt) - k \sin(\pi t)$$
i.e.
$$ \pi (\sin(k(t+T)-\sin(kt)) = k (\sin(\pi (t+T)) - \sin(\pi t)) $$

or
$$ \pi ((\cos(kT)-1) \sin(kt) + \sin(kT) \cos(kt) = k ((\cos(\pi T)-1) \sin(\pi t) + \sin(\pi T) \cos(\pi t) $$

If $k \ne \pm \pi$ and $k \ne 0$, $\cos(k t), \sin(k t), \cos(\pi t)$ and $\sin(\pi t)$ are linearly independent, so for this to be an identity you need
$\cos(kT) = 1$ and $\cos(\pi T) = 1$.  That will require $k$ and $\pi$ to be rationally related.  Namely if $\cos(\pi T) = 1$, $T = m$ for some even integer $m$, and if $\cos(k T) = 1$ $kT = n \pi$ for some even integer $n$.  Thus $k = n \pi/m$.